# How to add JUnit to my Eclipse and how to run it?

Tags: eclipse, scala

I want to try some tests,and have accidentally removed JUnit

[image]

My prefrences in Eclipse

[image]

I have found 
http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/testingframeworks/index.html

[image]

What is my next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "Restore Defaults", or re-install Eclipse.
Once you have re-enabled JUnit, to run a test just right-click on the class and choose "Run As" -> "JUnit Test"